# Problemas con mi Servidor de Bases de Datos en Localhost

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Tengo mucho tiempo de utilizar el WAMP como mi servidor de php y phpmysql y siempre me ha funcionado sin problemas y he creado mis BD y tables bien, hace dos dias sin haber hecho nada tuve problemas para conectarme a una BD con la cual he estado trabajand por varios dias y pude ver que en PHPMyadmin salia que el servidor es MSQL y no Localhost como se muestra en la siguiente imagen, como pueden ver aparece **Servidor:MSQL** y ahi deberia de decir **Servidor:Localhost** el problema se me hace mas grande porque no me aparecen las veces de datos  y no puedo trabjar con ellas, que puede ser el problema? como se puede corregir? de anteano gracias por la ayuda

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo único que veo raro en tu imagen es el puerto `3308` en lugar de `3306` y que en la url tienes `?server=2`. Todo lo demás se ve igual que el mío.